# Add-in that adds code to new Excel Workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to change my add-in so that it, when you would open a new Workbook, will open a new Sheet and then create a new Event Procedure in that new Sheet.

I've gotten to the point where I can "Sheets.Add" and ".CreateEventProc" using a macro button combination, but the issue comes when trying to use the **add-in's** Workbook to automate the process. The add-in loads in first, thus "Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject" can't find the new active workbook.

Is it possible to do this? If so, is there a work around needed or am I just missing something obvious?

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Excel.Application

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set App = Excel.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_NewWorkbook(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    Range("T2").Value = 100
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Call CreateEventProcedure

End Sub

Public Sub CreateEventProcedure()

Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
Dim NumLines As Long
Dim LineNum As Long
Dim ProcName As String
Dim ProcKind As VBIDE.vbext_ProcKind
Const DQUOTE = """" ' one " character

Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Sheet2")
Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
With CodeMod
    LineNum = .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1
    Do Until LineNum >= .CountOfLines Or ProcName = "Worksheet_Change"
        ProcName = .ProcOfLine(LineNum, ProcKind)
        LineNum = .ProcStartLine(ProcName, ProcKind) + _
                .ProcCountLines(ProcName, ProcKind) + 1
    Loop

    If ProcName = "Worksheet_Change" 
        GoTo Exi
    End If

    'Now, create a Change Event on Sheet2
    LineNum = .CreateEventProc("Change", "Worksheet")
```

Comment: When asking questions about your existing code, it's best to include the code.

Comment: I understand though I didn't think it wasn't necessary given the question has less to do with my current coding and more about whether or not it's possible to use an add-in to hard write into a newly opened Workbook. However, if you really need it I can show what I got.

Comment: It's up to you - if you want answers then questions with code do much better here.  It's a little difficult to follow your question since you seem to be using "worksheet" where maybe you mean "workbook'

Comment: Ah I see. I need to edit my original post. It seems I made some mistakes on the post. I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: Exactly how are you triggering that procedure ?

Comment: Right now it's through the macro short-cut key press "Ctrl-Shift-D" What I tried which prompted this post is using this:
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Call CreateEventProcedure
End Sub`
This function was used in the Add-ins Workbook

Comment: Unless you're adding the "new" workbook programmatically (in which case you can control the flow, assign that to an object, modify it's VBComponents, etc.) the add-in will need a `WithEvents` instance of `Excel.Application` class, and then you can monitor application-level events, such as the `_NewWorkbook` event, and you call your functions/subs from there to add the code module/event procedure to the new workbook. There may be another way to do this if you scope a module-level variable for the "new" workbook, but I'd have to tinker with that...

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like I could make it work but I have very little knowledge of creating custom events. I've been reading up on it and I came up with some code to represent my limited of my understanding of it. 
`Public WithEvents EClass As Excel.Application`
`Private Sub EClass_NewWorkbook()`
`Call CreateEventProcedure`
`End Sub`
Create the global event variable to Store events on the Excels application level and then run the Sub when the New Workbook Event pops. This is wrong of course, as this doesn't work when I tried using it in my add-in. Any extra knowledge would be awesome.

Comment: Well I got it to work for opening brand new Workbooks but it doesn't work for existing ones. Is there an event that looks for that? `_WorkbookOpen` Doesn't work because the event triggers before the sheets even load.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a template workbook that already contains the code?  Just take a copy of that rather than creating a new book, adding code, etc.

Comment: No, because we are using another program that can export files into Excel. Besides, this a more fun solution. :3

Answer (score 0):

For those who care, I got the process working with a minor complication. Here's what I did:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents ExApp As Excel.Application

Public Sub ExApp_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)
Dim StrPrompt As String
Dim strTitle As String
Dim iRet As Integer
StrPrompt = "Want to create event?"
strTitle = "Event?"
On Error GoTo 0
iRet = MsgBox(StrPrompt, vbYesNo, strTitle)
If iRet = vbYes Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    Call CreateEventProcedure
End If
    On Error GoTo 0
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        Call CreateEventProcedure
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set ExApp = Excel.Application
End Sub
```

I created the Yes/No prompt to Bypass the first 'run-time _Global' error and then the excel workbook actually loads, the prompt asks me again then I click yes and everything works fine. Also, this works with only one prompt needed when opening workbooks when already in excel.